# how to convert combination string to array like this?

Tags: php

I have already tried this problem, I have small question this below is my input:

```
AA-1001AB-1002
```

my question this combination string with number, word and symbol on above, and convert to array or json:

```
["AA-1001","AB-1002"]
```

thanks for help :)

Comment: Are the elements always the same length? If not, how does the code know where each one ends?

Comment: If they're always the same length, just write a loop that uses `substr()`, incrementing the start index by the length.

Comment: i tried this, using combination of `preg_replace` `explode` but is same

Comment: @Barmar can u write that code? string of `AA-1001` not always same, sometimes `AA-100` but the 2 word before '-' is always same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all()` to get all the matches of a pattern.

```
$string = "AA-1001AB-1002";
preg_match_all('/[A-Z]{2}-\d+/', $string, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];
print_r($result);
```

The regular expression matches two uppercase letters, hyphen, followed by any number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = "AA-1001AB-1002";
$arr = str_split($input, 7);
print_r($arr);
```

If you need JSON array, as possibly(?) indicated in your question:

```
$jarr = json_encode($arr);
echo $jarr;
```

Comment: json is also fine

Answer (score 0):

You can substr them and put two string into array:

```
$str = "AA-1001AB-1002";
$result = [ substr($str, 0, 7), substr($str, 7, 7) ];
var_dump($result);
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: string of `AA-1001` not always same, sometimes `AA-100` but the length 2 word before '-' is always same